# How to query in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

this is my first time asking questions and this is basically my last resort in finding some answers. Im a noob and beginner in javascript so please use simple terms with me.

So i have an issue. I dont know how to query. 
- As in do i put all my queries in one script or do i have to split them up to different scripts. 
- Right now, i have a server.js and i put all my codes in there. including queries. So how do i run just one of them. 
- and also if there is such a thing for me to query for just another number like 4. Do i have to go back to the script to manually change from '110' to '4' or can i just enter it somewhere.

Some examples are:
//length of 110

```
db.collection.find({length: "110"}, function(err, collection) {
  if( err || !collection) console.log("No collections with 110 in length");
  else collection.forEach( function(length) {
    console.log(length);
  } );
});
```

//shows record of length 110 and length 340

```
var length = ['110', '340']
length = length.join('|');
var re = new RegExp(length, 'i')
db.collection.find({length:{$regex: re}}, function(err, collection) {
  if( err || !collection ) console.log("User not found");
  else collection.forEach (function(length){
   console.log(length);
 });
});
```

How do i query to only run for one of them in mongodb. Appericiate the help alot guys

Comment: Not sure i understand your question. Are you asking about querying or general node.js project directory structure : Models, Controllers, Routes, Configs etc. ?

Comment: about querying. As in is there a way for the user to enter what they want the record to produce or not. For example, if i want the record to show number 4, i have to key it in the terminal or do i have to manually go back to the javascript and edit from there from length = "110" to length = "4"

Answer (score 0):

You already know that node.js is used for making servers. So there are 2 ways you can query the database. Since you're new to node, I'm going to list both the ways :

**1.A http GET for querying data (Standard Way)**
You can write a simple http server and set a route for getting the type of data you want.I've written a small file so that you can understand:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Db settings
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';

function getConnection(url, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(dbErr, dbRes) {
    if(dbErr) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    callback(null, dbRes);
  });
}

// Configure app to use bodyparser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 7013;
app.set('port', port);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.ip+ ":"+port + req.url + " "+req.method);
  next();
});

app.get('/getCityData', function(req, res, next) {
  var cityName = req.query.city;

  getConnection(url, function(conErr, db) {
    if(conErr) {
      return res.send("ERROR IN GETTING connection");
    }

    var cityCollection = db.collection('cities');
    cityCollection.find({"city":cityName}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if(err) return res.send("error in querying data");

      db.close();
      res.send(result);
    });
  });
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port "+app.get('port'));
});
```

You can query the server using curl or postman like this :
[image]

**2.Using command line arguments :**
You can also do it the easy way using command line arguments by passing the parameter to query, but it's less flexible:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';

function getConnection(url, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(dbErr, dbRes) {
    if(dbErr) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    callback(null, dbRes);
  });
}

var cityName = process.argv[2]; // that's the argument you'd receive
getConnection(url, function(conErr, db) {
  if(conErr) {
    return res.send("ERROR IN GETTING connection");
  }

  var cityCollection = db.collection('cities');
  cityCollection.find({"city":cityName}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if(err) return res.send("error in querying data");

    db.close();
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Pass that commandline argument like this while executing file :[image]

I hope it helps